# How to enable landscape mode for lockscreen in LineageOS 20 on Samsung Tab S6 Lite?

Tags: lock-screens, screen, lineageos, magisk, auto-rotation

LineageOS has been a huge improvement in terms of responsiveness and customization compared to Samsung OneUI. However on Samsung Tab S6 Lite (which mostly is set horizontally on table) the lockscreen being fixed in portrait mode is a huge drawback. I have to enter password with my head tilted and need to shake the tablet to make display horizontal again.

An [old reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/6vu7ub/lock_screen_rotation_on_tablets/) suggests that adding `log.tag.launcher_force_rotate=VERBOSE` and
`lockscreen.rot_override=true` to /system/build.prop will solve the problem, but I had no luck after changing the build.prop file in recovery mode. Even if it worked, build.prop will be overwritten after each LOS update.

I also tried installing MagiskHide Props Config and adding the abovementioned properties. But it also doesn't change anything. Other Magisk or LSPosed modules I found can force app rotation but not lockscreen.

It will be much appreciated if someone can give a hint of possible ways to enable horizontal lockscreen, preferably systemless.